# Best way to pass a flag to Node.js depending on Node version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When Node.js is `>6.3` I need to pass `--preserve-symlinks`.

I have about 50+ modules that have a `package.json` like so:

```
"scripts": {
  "gulp": "./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js",
  "start": "node main/server.js"
},
```

What is the best way to do this? If the flag is turned on my default some day I will need to update this too.

I am thinking that I will need to abandon npm run-scripts in this case and just have a single script which will determine the version to use.

---

Similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/691133/always-run-node-with-the-harmony-flag

PM2 has a `node_args` option: https://futurestud.io/blog/pm2-how-to-start-your-app-with-node-js-v8-arguments

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
"scripts": {
  "gulp": "./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js",
  "start": "node `node -v | sed 's/v//' | awk '{if($1 > 6.3) print \"--preserve-symlinks\"}'` main/server.js"
},
```